How to add custom select dropdown to a dialog/modal that should scroll
I have a dialog component in my angular app. There is a list that needs to scroll with form elements associated with each item. Looking at the picture it should make sense. This is my issue. When the container scrolls (overflow: auto) my absolutely positioned dropdown list actually takes up space in the scroll container. Why? What should I do?
Bellow I have two pictures. One where I have overflow: 'auto' and one where I don't.


Here is the relevant code:
<div class="education-list">
    @for (item of education; track item.id) {
        <div class="education">
            <div class="name-row">
                <form-input
                    class="name-input"
                    [inputFormGroup]="form"
                    [inputFormControlName]="'name-' + item.id"
                    label="School or Institution"
                    type="text"
                    [required]="true"
                    [useErrorMessage]="false"
                    backgroundColor="#FFF"
                ></form-input>
                <div class="delete-button" (click)="removeEducation(item.id)">
                    <mat-icon class="delete-icon" [inline]="true" class="delete-icon">delete</mat-icon>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dates-row">
                <single-select
                    class="date-select-input"
                    [inputFormGroup]="form"
                    [inputFormControlName]="'fromMonth-' + item.id"
                    [options]="[]"
                    label="Month"
                    [required]="true"
                    [useErrorMessage]="false"
                    [clearable]="false"
                    backgroundColor="#FFF"
                    [listMaxHeight]="130"
                >
                </single-select
                ><single-select
                    class="date-select-input"
                    [inputFormGroup]="form"
                    [inputFormControlName]="'fromYear-' + item.id"
                    [options]="yearOptions"
                    label="Year"
                    [required]="true"
                    [useErrorMessage]="false"
                    [clearable]="false"
                    backgroundColor="#FFF"
                    [listMaxHeight]="130"
                >
                </single-select>
                <p class="to-text">- to -</p>
                <single-select
                    class="date-select-input"
                    [inputFormGroup]="form"
                    [inputFormControlName]="'toMonth-' + item.id"
                    [options]="[]"
                    label="Month"
                    [required]="true"
                    [useErrorMessage]="false"
                    [clearable]="false"
                    backgroundColor="#FFF"
                    [listMaxHeight]="130"
                >
                </single-select
                ><single-select
                    class="date-select-input"
                    [inputFormGroup]="form"
                    [inputFormControlName]="'toYear-' + item.id"
                    [options]="[]"
                    label="Year"
                    [required]="true"
                    [useErrorMessage]="false"
                    [clearable]="false"
                    backgroundColor="#FFF"
                    [listMaxHeight]="130"
                >
                </single-select>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>

.education-list {
    max-height: 50rem;
    min-height: 10rem;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;

    .education {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 1rem;
        &:nth-of-type(even) {
            background-color: $rowHightlight;
        }

        .name-row {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            gap: 1rem;
        }

        &:not(:last-of-type) {
            margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
        }

        .delete-button {
            width: 3.1rem;
            height: 3.1rem;
            background-color: $secondary50;
            border: 1px solid $secondary100;
            border-radius: 0.3rem;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            margin-top: 1.5rem;
            cursor: pointer;
            .delete-icon {
                width: 2rem;
                height: 2rem;
                font-size: 2rem;
            }
        }

        .name-input {
            flex: 1;
        }
    }

    .dates-attended {
        margin: 0.5rem 0;
        font-weight: 500;
    }

    .dates-row {
        margin-top: 1rem;
        margin-right: 4rem;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 1rem;

        .date-select-input {
            flex: 1;
        }

        .to-text {
            font-weight: 500;
            font-size: 1.2rem;
            margin-top: 1rem;
        }
    }
}

and keep in mind, the select dropdown lists are absolutely positioned relative to their select box
